# Why can't I query certain fields in Prisma?

Tags: prisma

I need to be able to access certain fields of a Prisma model, but they always come back undefined even though I can see that the data exists in Prisma Studio.

Here is my model for **Goods** in schema.prisma:

```
model Good {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  title String
  completed Boolean @default(false)

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId String
}
```

Each Good has an id, title, etc. in addition to a **user**. However, when I log a Good to the console, it seems I can only access the title and id of the item. All the other expected fields are not present, and come back as undefined when I try to access them (i.e. console.log(good.user). Here's the output of console.log({good}):

```
{id: 'clcxxla0g0008ts5qjk248fzk', title: 'Title of good'}
```

What I need is to be able to query the **user** or **userId** for each Good, but I can't find a way to do this.

For more info, here is what what Prisma Studio data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the query that you are invoking?
If you need to get the relation fields i.e. User then you would need to use include: https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#include

Comment: Hi Narul, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It was a simple fix. In order to access the fields I wanted (i.e. user, username), I needed to add the user field to my query: `select: { id: true, title: true, completed: true, user: true }` After doing this, I was able to access the user field. I didn't realize you had to explicitly state which fields you want carried over in the query.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you were able to find the solution :)